# Does "cut something sideways" mean "cut it horizontally or vertically"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I heard some native speakers say "**cut the chicken/cake/piece of wood sideways**". Does "**cut something sideways**" mean "**cut it horizontally or vertically**"?

How do we know which way is horizontal or vertical?

Also, we have square cakes with words on them. Does "**cut it sideways**" mean "**cut it across the words**"?

We also have rectangular cakes.

You can see my pictures down here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would have to ask them exactly what they meant! I _can_ tell you that cutting a papaya or a rectangular cake on the long axis would be _lengthways_.

Comment: in most of these cases I wouldn't have a clue. Even in the case of a cake where I'd probably understand it as meaning a horizontal cut parallel to the plate, dividing it into a top and bottom half I'd ask for clarification before making the cut. I think describing directions of cuts is something us native speakers often confuse each other over